# how to extract detailed error info from onerror event of link tag

Tags: javascript

Below is the js code which creates the link

```
 const link = document.createElement('link');
 link.type = 'text/css';
 link.rel = 'stylesheet';
 link.onload = function(){}
 link.onerror = function(event){ console.log(event.message) }

 link.href ="source.css";
 document.head.appendChild(link);
```

the onerror returns event as first param, event.type = "error", how to extract the message from above. i tried event.message it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can not track HTTP errors here.

The [Reference](https://javascript.info/onload-onerror#script-onerror) here says:

> Important: Events onload/onerror track only the loading itself.
>
> Errors that may occur during script processing and execution are out
> of scope for these events. That is: if a script loaded successfully,
> then onload triggers, even if it has programming errors in it. To
> track script errors, one can use window.onerror global handler.

You have to use `window.onerror` for any loading related error catching.

Comment: well in this case we can't. but if we wanted to lazyload js scripts, we could use try catch block, or use XMLHtppRequest. right?

Comment: xmlhttprequests cannot be cached in browser, browser reads cache header of js, css and caches by link and script tags respectively.